# Ring theoretic characterisation of symmetric algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory

In https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.4559.pdf theorem 7 states that a finite dimensional algebra $A$ over an infinite field $k$ is symmetric iff $top(A)=soc(A)$ as bimodules and $[A,A]$ contains no right ideal.
It is left open whether this holds for finite fields. Only the direction:
"$top(A)=soc(A)$ as bimodules and $[A,A]$ contains no right ideal implies symmetric" is open.

> Question: Is this solved now?

How about this approach: Let $k$ be a finite field.
Assume $top(A)=soc(A)$ as bimodules and $[A,A]$ contains no non-zero right ideal.
Let $K$ be the algebraic closure of $k$ and $B=K \otimes_k A$. $top(A)=soc(A)$ implies that $A$ is selfinjective and thus also $B$ is selfinjective.
$A$ is symmetric iff $B$ is symmetric as a $K$-algebra. Using the theorem 7 for infinite fields, this should be equivalent to $[B,B]=K \otimes_k [A,A]$ not containing any minimal right ideal (that is a simple module) $S$.
Now does $S \subset K \otimes_k [A,A]$ and "restricting" to $k$ give that $L \subset [A,A]$ for some simple $A$-module $L$? I always work with quiver algebras and can not really imagine what is going on there.